# Select tag inside hyperlink problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, hyperlink

I have simplified my page and here what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<style>
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div select {
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('div').click(function(){
                        return false;
                        });
</script>


</head>

<body>
<a href="#############">
<img src="preview_image" />
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <select>
            <option value="default" selected>choose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The main idea is that I have a "A" hyperlink tag, inside which is included DIV with INPUT and SELECT inside.

What my goal is: when I put text into INPUT and when I select option from SELECT - the parent A hyperlink should not trigger.

I have tried to fix it with "return false", but looks this is not helping.

Also I have some problem in Mozilla FF: SELECT is not choosing any value whatever you choose there in the list. It is always left as "choose"

---

**UPD**

the only problem left is the SELECT behavior inside A-hyperlink in FireFox. I have FF version 3.6.3 And the behavior is when I select option from SELECT it is not set as chosen. In all the rest browsers seem to work correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to have the `<a>` in the first place? It's not valid to have a `div` in it and could cause trouble.

Comment: Yeah, whats the purpose of the A-tag? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, I know that block element is not correct to put inside inline. This is what I have as a "heritage". If to do it properly the whole functionality should be rewritten, which I want to avoid.

But it looks like the problem I described is not because of this. It is occuring even if I omit DIV from the markup.

The main ide: there are pictures on the site.
And on hover - there is button (DIV) displayed over the picture. On click - there is INPUT and SELECT added to this button for further action.

But sometimes images are included in A tag (e.g. preview), and there occur problems I described.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, clicking on the Link should not open the linked webppage, but show the Select? When should the link be used?

Comment: I have added to the initial code IMG. So actually when you click IMAGE - the link should be opened, as link is directing to the full-size image. But when I'm over DIV and for example click INPUT or SELECT - I don't want the A-tag to work. I want just to put value in INPUT and select option from SELECT.

Comment: I'm not sure how the other browsers are "behaving correctly"...you can't have a `<select>` inside an `<a>`, at all.  It's invalid HTML...with invalid HTML there is no "correct" behavior, the browser is free to (quite validly) refuse to even render your page if it so desires, and it'd be within spec. You **need** to re-structure this, trying to trick various browsers into doing what you want is not the correct solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach: everything is contained in this link element. So theoretically, a browser is right to assume that anything that gets clicked inside this A-tag is clicking the link. Even thought this may work differently for some browsers, and lead to the behaviour you would like, I would doubt that the behaviour is consistent over all user agents. Hence I don't see how there is any way to make this work reliably without getting rid of the A-element, respectively moving the A-element so its only around the image (which is the behaviour you desire):

```
<a href="#############">
   <img src="preview_image" />
</a>
<div>
   <input type="text" value="" />
   <select>
            <option value="default" selected>choose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that this DIV is added through JS on page load. And it is added to every image. Images sometimes are wrapped with A and sometimes are not. So for general purpose the DIV was added after every image, because of this it is sometimes inside A-tag and sometimes not.

Actually, the answer in the previous post is stopping A-tag following. But there is another problem in FireFox, where there is some problem with choosing value in SELECT element inside A-tag. It is simply not chosen.
If you have any advice on this - I would appreciate. Tnx.

Comment: Can't you change the script to add the div after the surrounding a-tag instead of directly after the immage?

Comment: As I said, I dont see how this will work properly across all current (and future Browsers). As Chris_I wrote: start redesigning it now, it will have to be redesigned eventually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't know, what you need your entire `<a><div>...` construct for, in any case you should put your script into a ready() block, so that it executes when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('div').click(function(){
        return false;
   });

});
```

Comment: thanks.

But in the firefox, while it stopping the A-link to go, the value in the SELECT list is not chosen. I have wrote about it in the initial.
It is always left as "choose".

Comment: @volder: That won't work. It's simply not designed to work. Change the structure, at the end of the day, it will save you a lot of time and headache.